# php move_uploaded_file permission denied - 2 dirs, same owner, same perms, 1 ok , 1 fail

Tags: php

I have 2 upload folders within the same directory on the server (upload_one, and upload_two). my php code is able to upload to upload_one, but gets a "move_uploaded_file failed to open stream: Permission denied" error on upload_two. I have read similar questions on s/o, googled, etc. I have tried this:
- change permission to 777 (temporarily, to test): same result
- restart apache / reboot instance: same result
- delete upload_two and create a new directory: same result
- clone upload_one (clone owner/permission) and rename upload_two: same result
I am completely stumped.  Any advice is welcome.

Comment: is the fail one have deeper path.

Comment: NO, same exact depth.  They are both in the same folder /var/www/html/ and they are both identical.  One will accept the upload from the client, the other won't.

Comment: Are you calling `move_uploaded_file` twice?

Comment: no, just calling it once to upload 1 file. Using the exact same code, if I change my upload path from upload_one to upload_two and vice-versa, it will consistently work for upload_one and consistently fail for upload_two.  They have the same group (www), owner (apache), and permissions 755. I have no idea what's going on.  Even if I try to create a new upload_two, with the same exact feature, the new one will fail too.

Comment: Have you tried disabling selinux?  try to **setenforce 0**

Comment: Wow.  That fixed it.  Now I need to research what problems removing selinux could cause, but it certainly took care of my problem.  Thank you!